# How to print CData content while parsing xml local file with python?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, cdata

So I have a XML file from a local folder that I want to scrape using Python. It has CData and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <trial xmlns="urn::trial">
      <drksId><![CDATA[DRKS00000024]]></drksId>
      <firstDrksPublishDate><![CDATA[2008-09-05T12:36:54.000+02:00]]></firstDrksPublishDate>
      <firstPartnerPublishDate><![CDATA[2004-01-15T00:00:00.000+01:00]]></firstPartnerPublishDate>
      ......
```

I tried:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Et
tree=Et.parse(filename)
root=tree.getroot()
print(root.find('drksId').text)
```

Output:
I am getting root.find('drksId') as None. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to search element considering namespace:

```
ns = {'ns': 'urn::trial'}
drksId = root.find('./ns:drksId', ns)
print(drksId.text)
```

Comment: Hey so this works for this particular tag. Other that have hierarchy like <trial><status><state><![CDATA[complete-complete]]></state></status>......</trial>. This method is not working for such content

Comment: As the namespace is declared on root element, it should be applied for all children as well. In your example it will be `ns:trial/ns:status/ns:state`.